# Send email from a separated file using Swift Mailer

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-blade, swiftmailer

With Laravel Mailer we can send email from a separated file. We mentioned the file name as a first parameter of `send()` function. As an example:

```
Mail::send('emails.billRequest',$data, function($message){
    // rest of code
});
```

In above example `emails.billRequest` is the file name I want to send. This process is working fine with me, no problem with that.

**My Problem is**

Currently I am using `Swift Mailer`. My code is:

```
$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.email.com',587,'tls')
    ->setUsername('myemailaddress@email.com')
    ->setPassword('mypassword');

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('test subject')
    ->setFrom(['sender@email.com'=>'sender'])
    ->setTo(['reciver@email.com'=>'reciver'])
    ->setBody('<p>this is a test body</p>','text/html');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

This code also working perfectly. My question is, is there any way to keep my email's body in a separated file?

Writing a long html email inside `setBody()` will look messy.

Comment: If you are using Laravel why must you use Swift_Mailer directly

Comment: @Digitlimit Because, I have to send different emails from different smtp servers and email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem with that.

Instead of:

```
->setBody('<p>this is a test body</p>','text/html');
```

use

```
->setBody(view('emails.billRequest', $data)->render());
```

Construction:

```
view('emails.billRequest', $data)->render()
```

will generate your Blade file `emails/billRequest.blade.php` and pass `$data` to template and render it into string so you can now use it as e-mail body

**EDIT**

OF course If I were you, I would reconsider using `SwiftMailer` directly when it's not really needed.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. The email is sending as I want, but in plain text format. I just add `text/html` as a second argument. Like this: `->setBody(view('emails.billRequest',$data)->render(),'text/html');`